# Load header file at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to be able to download a header file (.h) from a remote server and load it at runtime and use its contents - it is mainly arrays, structs etc. How can I do this with the iOS sdk in Objective C?

Comment: No header files are only used by the compiler.

Comment: Can you give us some context - what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you are planning to load a class at runtime, use this for reference..but I doubt this is available for iOS...https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingCode/LoadingCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000052-SW1

Comment: Yes sure. These .h files contain arrays and structs. They describe 3D models exported with the software Blender. I need to be able to download different models i.e. different header files which will always have the same names for their properties and access them at runtime.

Comment: here is an example of such .h file:  #ifndef _BLENDER_EXPORT_H_
#define _BLENDER_EXPORT_H_

#define OBJECTS_COUNT 3

float transformations[][16]={....};
unsigned int faces_count[]={....};
unsigned int vertex_count[]={...};
unsigned int vertex_offset_table []={...};
unsigned int indices_offset_table []={...};
struct vertex_struct vertices[]={...};

#define INX_TYPE GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT
unsigned short indexes[]={ ... };
#endif

Comment: You can download heder files any time but you can use them only like text file with some info. It's impossible to use it to change app.

Comment: @gosho_ot_pochivka, you should not mix the _compiler_ time environment with the _runtime_ environment, and you would see why there is no point in your question.

Comment: It sounds like your actual issue is specifically about loading 3D model data into your app, not generally about parsing C header files. Might be good to put that context in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need a C compiler to parse those header files, and that's sort of overkill if all they contain is 3D model data. (Not to mention disallowed for the App Store.)

You should look into alternate formats for getting 3D data into your app. I believe there might be third party libraries for formats like Wavefront OBJ, and in iOS 8 you can use SceneKit to load Collada DAE and Alembic ABC files (but only after they've been compressed by Xcode).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I will go for. It was more of a curious topic for me and I wondered if objective c had something similar to eval() in js where I can generate whole methods/classes from a string at runtime but I guess this isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

Would it help to grab a remote plist and deal with the configuration at runtime?  You could do something like this:

```
NSURL *plistUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://theurlto.com/your.plist"];
NSDictionary *remotePlistDictionary;
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:plistUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10.0];
NSError *error;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error];

if (!error)
{
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    remotePlistDictionary = [responseString propertyList];
}
```

The dictionary remotePlistDictionary will contain the configuration.  That plist could even be generated dynamically based on URL parameters.